# ServiceAutoStartProvider Not Invoked

Tags: iis, azure, iis-8

I have an AutoStartProvider which is not getting invoked on our IIS 8.0 production environment.  It works great on our IIS 7.5 development environment.  I've created logging functions from the AutoStartProvider to the event log and to SQL Server.  Both ways of logging work fine from our development environment, but not on production.  I fear the AutoStartProvider is not getting invoked.

The following are relevant snippets from the production environment's applicationHost.config file.  Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Application Pool:

```
    <add name="1f582a90-1883-4887-bef8-156e3a7e0099" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
        <processModel identityType="NetworkService" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
        <recycling>
            <periodicRestart time="00:00:00" />
        </recycling>
    </add>
```

Application:

```
        <application path="/" applicationPool="1f582a90-1883-4887-bef8-156e3a7e0099" enabledProtocols="http,https" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" serviceAutoStartProvider="VINspinAutoStartProvider" preloadEnabled="true">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="F:\sitesroot\3" />
        </application>
```

AutoStartProvider:

```
<serviceAutoStartProviders>
    <add name="VINspinAutoStartProvider" type="VINspin.Core.Web.Providers.VINspinAutoStartProvider,VINspin.Core.Web" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

Answer (score -1):

did you check if you get errors in the Windows Event Manager? For me, that got me to find the problem a short time ago.